# Facebook Like/Share buttons small when user is not logged in

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, plugins

I have a container on a page I'm working on that contains social media plugin's for twitter and Facebook. I use the 'data-size="large"' setting to set the size of the facebook button to large, (same applies to Twitter)

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

When the user's browser is Logged into facebook the buttons display as they are supposed to.

How it looks when user is logged into Facebook (correct sizing)

[image: logged-in]

How it looks when user is not logged into facebook

[image: logged-out]

Being logged out of Twitter has no effect on the size of Twitter the button.

I've tried using the facebook Javascript SDK and iFrame with the same result.

All I need is a way to force the logged out buttons to remain large.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you give us more information, or atleast give the link to your website if you can so we can test.

Comment: As you can see, the icon displayed in the like button is different as well. So most likely this has to do with Facebook rolling out a new version of their like button – and FB usually does this gradually, meaning not all users get the update at the same time. Therefor, you can get to see a different result depending on whether you are logged in or not, and even two different logged-in users might see different versions. Nothing you can do about that, expect wait until this update is rolled out for everyone.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Not what I was hoping to hear! but makes sense. Hopefully they'll have reached us by the time we go live. Thanks!